# Excel: How can I make cell references dynamic?

Tags: dynamic, excel-formula, cross-reference

Very weird scenario: I have a very complex excel sheet which I want to make as less prone to errors as possible.
The reason for this is, the sheet potentially gets extended in the future.

FirstWorksheet:

```
Cell A1: Parameter 1
Cell A2: 1.500 
Cell A3: 1.600
Cell A4: 2.000
Cell A5: =Average(A2:A4)
Cell A6:
Cell A7: Parameter 2
Cell A8: 1.500 
Cell A9: 1.600
Cell A10: 2.000
Cell A11: =Average(A8:A10)
```

SecondWorksheet:

```
Cell A1: Parameter 1 Average
Cell A2: =FirstWorksheet!A5
Cell A3:
Cell A4: Parameter 2 Average
Cell A5: =FirstWorksheet!A11
```

Now if I want to prevent typos in the references, instead of manually writing the "=FirstWorksheet!A11 into cell A5 of the second worksheet, I'd like to copy cell A2 and paste it into cell A5.

The problem is, if I do that, excel does not make "=FirstWorksheet!A11" but "=FirstWorksheet!A8", because obviously A5 is three rows below A2, so at the moment I have to manually correct those references each time I copy them.

so I want something like this in the cell in sheet 2:

```
=FirstWorksheet!A<some formula in dependence of the current row of sheet two>
```

is that at all possible?

I tried something like this to test it (assume that A1 contains through whatever calculation the row number which I need to refer to in a second sheet):

```
A1: 1234
A2: A
A3: 1
A4: =A2&A3
A5: =indirect(A4)
```

Then, at this point, cell A5 shows "1234" as value, so that would be the hypothetical cell I want to refer to, so I know the calculation works.

with this, I theoretically can calculate the correct row number, but how do I get to use this number as a dynamic cell reference?

If I try it like this (going with above example):

```
="=FirstWorksheet!A"&Indirect(FirstWorksheet!A5)
```

I *would* expect the formula to work like I have manually entered

```
=FirstWorksheet!A1234
```

but of course it doesn't (I simply get an "#REF!" error)

So the question is: Is what I am trying to do even possible in the first place, and if yes, where is my error and is there maybe a way easier way to do it?

As a reminder, I could easily just manually correct the references after copying for now, it would be maybe 1-2 hours to do so and be done with it, but this would be prone to errors, and as the document is extended in quite regular intervals, it would be extremely handy if you just needed to copy a block in the excel and everything else is done automatically, reducing the risk for errors even further.

Comment: `FirstWorksheet!A5` is already `1234` so you don't need `INDIRECT`.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the first part inside the `INDIRECT`.

`=INDIRECT("FirstWorksheet!A"&FirstWorksheet!A5)`